# MySQL cursor issues: what did i do wrong?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I've been working on this code that's supposed to do this according to the book:

> Write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named test.
>   This stored procedure should create a cursor for a result set that
>   consists of the product_name and list_price columns for each product
>   with a list price that’s greater than $700. The rows in this result
>   set should be sorted in descending sequence by list price. Then, the
>   procedure should display a string variable that includes the
>   product_name and list price for each product so it looks something
>   like this: `"Gibson SG", "2517.00" | "Gibson Les Paul", "1199.00""`

Unfortunately what my code does is return a null value instead of anything. what am i doing wrong?

```
USE my_guitar_shop;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;

DELIMITER //

Create Procedure test()
Begin
    DECLARE names_var VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE prices_var DECIMAL (8,2);
    DECLARE results VARCHAR(150);
    DECLARE done TINYINT;

    DECLARE products_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT product_name, list_price FROM products;

    DECLARE continue handler for not found set done = 1;
    SET done = 0;

    OPEN products_cursor;

    testloop : loop
    FETCH products_cursor INTO names_var, prices_var;
    IF done = 1 then leave testloop;
    END IF;

    IF prices_var > 700 THEN
        SET results = concat(results, "names_var", ', ', "prices_var", '|');
    END if;
    END loop testloop; 

    CLOSE products_cursor;

    SELECT results;


END //

DELIMITER ;

Call test;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will return **`null`** if any argument is **`null`**. I suspect what is happening is that your select is returning a **`null`** from one of the rows, and that is wiping out the entire content of `results`.

To handle this case, you would use the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), like this:

```
IF prices_var > 700 THEN
    SET results = concat(results, '"', COALESCE(names_var, ' '), '", "', COALESCE(prices_var, ' '), '" | ');
```

The calls to `COALESCE`return the value of the variable if it is not null, or the blank string `' '` if the variable is null.

(I think I've got all the single- and double-quotes in that output straight, but I make no promises. ;)

Comment: That didn't do it. All it did was change the name of the column, I haven't needed to do parameters for these, just a result.

Comment: Okay. I just read the docs for `CONCAT`, and I have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by initializing the results variable before entering the loop and taking away the quotations around names_var and prices_var

```
Create Procedure test()
BEGIN
DECLARE names_var VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE prices_var DECIMAL (8,2);
DECLARE results VARCHAR(400);
DECLARE done INT;


DECLARE products_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT product_name, list_price 
    FROM products 
    WHERE list_price > 700
    ORDER BY list_price DESC;

DECLARE continue handler for not found set done = 1;
SET done = 0;
SET results = '';

OPEN products_cursor;

testloop : loop
FETCH products_cursor INTO names_var, prices_var;

IF done = 1 THEN
LEAVE testloop;
END IF;

SET results = concat('"', names_var, '"', ',', '"', prices_var, '"', "|", results);

END loop testloop; 

SELECT results;
CLOSE products_cursor;

END //
```